# How to check if the system has license for `Simulink Coder?

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-deployment

Similar to how the command `checkout RTW_Embedded_Coder` shows whether an e-coder license is available or not, how to verify if a Simulink Coder license is available or not?

Comment: Why do you want to know? Presumably that's something only Simulink is concerned with...

Comment: Simulink complained while trying to build a model that the Simulink Coder license is missing. So after some debug steps, wanted to confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The license names for MATLAB products are confusing as they have changed over time as products have evolved. Licence name "RTW_Embedded_Coder" is "Embedded Coder" and "Simulink Coder" has the license name "Real-Time_Workshop"

```
license('test','Real-Time_Workshop')
```

will return 1 if the license is available for check out or not.

See [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/377731-how-do-features-from-license-correspond-to-names-from-ver) on the Mathworks support pages for a more complete list of license vs product names.

Or [this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195425-how-do-i-get-a-license-feature-name-for-a-toolbox-in-ver) tell you how to perform the name translation directly inside MATLAB

```
com.mathworks.product.util.ProductIdentifier.get('Simulink Coder').getFlexName
```

which returns `Real-Time_Workshop`

Comment: Thank you. With the test returning 1 and also my license issue for Simulink coder being fixed in parallel, I'm now able to build without license issues. Thank you :)